# using profiler4j for profiling

Tags: java, profiling, call-graph

I want to use profiler4j to profile my simple java program which call 2 methods. I would be interested in call graph view. I followed following link to run the profiler.

```
http://profiler4j.sourceforge.net/#Tutorial
```

when I try to run the profiler by

`java -javaagent:profiler4j-1.0-beta2/agent.jar test/MainController`

I get the output as shown in the tutorial link. but I have to press ctrl+c to come to the prompt again.(I use linux) Then I try to run the console.jar to view the output produced.

```
java -jar profiler4j-1.0-beta2/console.jar
```

but I don't see ANYTHING in the output. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong ? I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Profiler4j is quite old project. There is now [JVisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) included with JDK since Java 6 and it has an excellent [profiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html).